# Integral $\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}$

Tags: integration, substitution

I understand that I will be using trig substitution, and tangent will be what is used, but I get confused later down the road when integrating with the trig.

Comment: There is no need for trig. Rewrite the integrand as $\frac{x\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x^2}$ and let $u^2=1+x^2$. Then $x\,dx=u\,du$ and we end up integrating $\frac{u^2}{u^2-1}=1+\frac{1}{u^2-1}$. On the second part use partial fractions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a trig substitution, take $x=\tan\left(u\right)
 $ to get $dx=\sec^{2}\left(u\right)
 $, $\sqrt{1+x^{2}}=\sqrt{1+\tan^{2}\left(u\right)}=\sec\left(u\right)
 $ and $x=\tan^{-1}\left(u\right)
 $. Then $$\int\frac{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}{x}dx=\int\csc\left(u\right)\sec^{2}\left(u\right)du=\int\csc\left(u\right)\left(1+\tan^{2}\left(u\right)\right)du=
 $$ $$=\int\frac{\sin\left(u\right)}{\cos^{2}\left(u\right)}du+\int\csc\left(u\right)du
 $$ and I think you can get it from here.